# How do you decide if a process has $s$ or $t$ channel Feynman diagram?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

Without working with Lagrangian, how can one explain if we are dealing with $s$ or $t$ channel diagrams? For example, for $\rm e^+e^-\to\gamma\gamma$, I thought $s$-channel diagram, but the solutions I have, show a $t$-channel diagram.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine this by using the vertices of the Standard Model (below) and building a Feynman diagram out of these vertices.

[image: Standard Model Vertices by Garyzx, distributed under CC-BY-SA 3.0]

The interaction $\rm e^+e^-\to e^+e^-$, known as [Bhabha scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_scattering), has interfering diagrams in both the s- and t-channels. In the s-channel, the two particles annihilate into a photon that then turns back into an electron and a positron, while in the t-channel, the two particles exchange an electron. Both of these processes use the second vertex below twice.

$\rm e^+e^-\to\gamma\gamma$, on the other hand, has no s-channel. This is because the positron and the electron can annihilate into a photon (or a Z boson), but neither a photon nor a Z boson couples to two photons. That is, there is no 3 photon vertex or $\rm Z\gamma\gamma$ vertex below. The only way to form $\rm e^+e^-\to\gamma\gamma$ at tree level is with an electron as an internal line.

Comment: Cheers Chris, this makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: One should point out that is all about rules for quantum number conservations (lepton, baryon, charge..)